# How to pass entire html img element with Base64String to server through ajax?

Tags: javascript, java, ajax, image, base64

Hi i am trying to ajax save contents of Rich text editor as such(Raw HTML content) in database.I have other inputs values along with this editor value to be passed along in ajax call...
hence i construct a json String with all inputs value in my page and send it in ajax as request param

```
&1_Question={
    SubRefNumber:"QuestionBank.js", 
    QuestionType:"Subjective",
    Level:"-----", 
    QBType:"-----",
    Question:"<p><img src=\\'data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRg..ICIiAiIg//Z\\' /></p>",              
    Hints:"null",
    SubjectiveSolution:"QuestionBank.js"
}&QuestionsKeyList=1_Question
```

i face problem with the img tag passed in request. my problem is that the Rich editor(Tinymce)i use converts uploaded images to base64 src data, hence when i try to save that base64 string, it contents gets modified somehow when passing to server....

```
$.ajax({
    url: saveUrl ,
    type: 'POST',
    data: dat ,    
    cache: false,        
    processData: false,                            
    success: function(response){

    }
});
```

the string saves in db without any issues but when i get the saved image to display again in page i get corrupted image... when i compared the base64 string sent from ajax and base64 string received in server before saving both were different !! some characters like '+' were missing when received @ server side...Why is it so..Please Guide...

Comment: Hi, can you put a sample of the base64 image before and after being sent to the server

Comment: why are you trying to send markup to the server? the issue might be that it exceeds the maximum post size. when you base64 encode a file you make it about 30% larger. you should upload it as a normal file.

Comment: What is `dat`. Not really a lot known here. Would try removing `processData:false`

Comment: I send images as base64 in many of my apps without issue, and I get very small images (<100kb typically). However, I don't use tinyMce's embed image option. I create a separate, custom image uploader to go along with the tinymce form input. Then I send base64 as a separate field to the server, and convert it to an image on the server.

Comment: It seems is most likely the result of URL parsing of data in ajax request including base64 data from a + to a white space. Probably a simple $str = str_replace(' ', '+', $str) before you save to DB should resolve it.

Comment: @RajeshK thanks a lot it worked!!